# Why does the OrderedDict __dict__ method always return an empty dictionary?

Tags: python

I'm building a recursively method that uses a list of strings and integers (the 'path') to return an item from a nested structure of generic classes, lists, tuples, dictionaries.

```py
def get_leaf(pytree, path):
    """
    Recuses down the path of the pytree
    """
    key = path[0]
    pytree = pytree.__dict__[key] if hasattr(pytree, '__dict__') else pytree[key]
    
    # Return param if at the end of path, else recurse
    return pytree if len(path) == 1 else get_leaf(pytree, path[1:])
```

This method works fine for *most* data types, but it fails when using ordered dictionaries because they have an `__dict__` method, but this method always returns an empty dictionary.

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
ordered_dict = OrderedDict({"item": 1})
print(ordered_dict.__dict__)
>>> {}
```

I don't understand why the ordered dictionary has this method, or why it always returns an empty dictionary.

Comment: because this method is not inherited from builtedin.dict, and is custom defined

Comment: @sahasrara62 It has nothing to do with inheritance, the `__dict__` attribute (it is not a method) contains the object's own attributes, and dictionary members are not attributes so they aren't in there.

Comment: Regarding your actual problem, I think it would make more sense to use `__getitem__` if it exists, and fallback to `__dict__` otherwise.